# How to save set a boolean property in the viewmodel, if any of its properties binding to the text box has error in the input

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

```
public class SampleViewModel
{
   public double InputA
   {get; set;}

   public double InputB
   {get; set;}

   public bool HasErrors
   {get; set;}
}
```

When this view model is binded to a usercontrol.xaml with two text boxes. And there is a main window which contains this usercontrol.xaml and has a submit button. 
The submit button should be enabled only if the input values to the textboxes are doubles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from my experience you can go two ways. if you want validate user input (eg. with IDataErrorInfo) then it would be best if all viewmodel properties are strings and then if the input is valid you can convert it to the model object type eg. double.

this is because if you create a double viewmodel property and bind to it the following can happen:

1. input a nice value 1.23 to textbox
2. through binding this value is in your viewmodel
3. the user set "abc" to the textbox
4. a binding exception is happen but the viewmodel is not notified and still 1.23
5. this means for the viewmodel all is still fine

another way would be to use behaviors or "special" controls to limit the input values to valid values.

Answer (score 0):

Bind HasError field to enable property of button and update your model as below.

```
class SampleViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        #endregion

        private double inputA = 0;

        public string InputA
        {
          get { return inputA.ToString(); }
          set 
          { 
            if(double.TryParse(value, out inputA))
    {
     OnPropertyChanged("InputA");
             UpdateHasError();
    }                
          }
        }

        private double inputB = 0;

        public string InputB
        {
          get { return inputB.ToString(); }
          set 
          { 
            if(double.TryParse(value, out inputB))
    {
     OnPropertyChanged("InputB");
             UpdateHasError();
    }                
          }
        }

        private bool hasError;

        public bool HasError
        {
            get { return hasError; }
            set 
            { 
                hasError = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("HasError");
            }
        }

        private void UpdateHasError()
        {
            //If inputA and inputB decimal we update hasError
            if(inputA > 0 && inputB > 0)
                HasError = true;
            else
                HasError = false;
        }
    }
```

Edit : Added UpdateHasError() calling code.

Comment: Who calls UpdateHasError?

Comment: Sorry.. I added UpdateHasError() calling part. It should be called when inputA or inputB updating.

Comment: In my case the setter property doesn't get fired when I am entering any illegal value. It just shows red border around the text box.

Comment: It because you bind textbox text property to a double property. Change its type to string and cast it into double inside setter.

Check updated code..

Comment: Is there any solution not changing the type from double to string?

Comment: did you look at my answer? the only way is to restrict entering  illegal values

Comment: Actually, I have used behavior.